# In Beamer, how to add institution to the footer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes

I am using Copenhagen and Wolverine. The footer is currently split into two sections, the left hand side has my name and the right hand side has the presentation name and the number of slides. See the image example for how it looks.

How do I edit so that First Last (RC) as opposed to First Last in the bottom left footer? Where RC is the short version of institution name? Given the long version includes the so much.

Cheers

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty   % Removes the interactive buttons
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}  % Removes the header sections

% ADDS SLIDE NUMBERS
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
   \oldmacro\hfill%
   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

% Additional packages needed
\usepackage{amsmath} % For ???
\usepackage{dsfont}  % For mathds font
\usepackage{hologo}  % For BibTeX font
\usepackage{lmodern} % For ???

%Information to be included in the title page:
 \title{Name of presentation}

 \author{First Last}

 \institute[RC]
 {
   Research Center \newline Department \newline University \newline \newline February 2018
 }

\date[\today]{}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=.35]{PICTURE.png}}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the footline template to include your desired information:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\title{Name of presentation}
\author{First Last}
\institute[RC]{Research Center \newline Department \newline University \newline \newline February 2018}
\date[\today]{}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=.35]{example-image}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank, you, that is great. So I can then remove this that I had? 

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
   \oldmacro\hfill%
   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

Comment: @Andre Yes, I included this in the new footline.